# Wait for volley response, then update ListView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

I want to data out of the mediawiki api, parse it, then put headings and paragraphs into a listview. In the code below, I create and set the adapter inside the onResponse method of the request, because if I do that outside, the request will not have finished yet.

I also override the getView method of the adapter because I want to format the items, e.g. bold and coloured headings. I tested this in another project and it works, but when put inside the onResponse method, this section no longer has any effect.

The solution I have in mind would be waiting for volley to complete the request before setting the listview on the main thread. I've read solutions about using futures and an asynctask, but it didn't work for me and I don't really understand it enough to try and fix it. Can anyone help?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&prop=extracts&titles=OSI%20model&exlimit=1";
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<p>(.*?)</p>|<ul>(?!<li>Mi)(.*?)</ul>|<span id=\\\\\"((?!Examples|Comparison_with_TCP.2FIP_model|See_also|References|External_links).*?)\\\\\">");
                        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(response);
                        ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
                        content.add("OSI Model");
                        while (matcher.find()){
                            String s = matcher.group();
                            s = s.replaceAll("</li>\\\\n<li>", "\n");
                            s = s.replaceAll("<p>|</p>|<b>|</b>|<i>|</i>|<ul>|</ul>|<li>|</li>|\\\\\">", "");
                            s = s.replaceAll("\\\\u00e9", "e");
                            s = s.replaceAll("\\\\u2013|\\\\u2014", " - ");
                            s = s.replaceAll("_|\\\\n", " ");
                            s = s.replaceAll("\\\\\"", "\"");
                            content.add(s);
                        }
                        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,content){
                            @Override
                            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                                TextView item = (TextView) super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
                                String itemText = super.getItem(position);
                                if (itemText.matches("<span id=\\\\\".+")){
                                    System.out.println("A");
                                    item.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9933"));
                                    item.setTypeface(item.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                                    item.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,20);
                                    item.setText(itemText.replaceAll("<span id=\\\\\"", ""));
                                }
                                return item;
                            }
                        };
                        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Use `error` in `onErrorResponse()` method. Make sure you added the internet permission in manifest too.

Comment: @Mohsen no errors, i have internet permission, it's just my overridden geView method that isn't doing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing this in your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Your regex is wrong, I recommend you to use this [regex-tool](https://www.browserling.com/tools/text-from-regex) to see what you are doing wrong.

I made a changes in your regex and I see something like this :

[image]

What I've changed is this :

```
 if (itemText.matches("<span id=\".+")){
```

But if you leave it like this you'll get problems when scrolling, so you have to do a tricky stuff. Modify it as your like

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,content){
                                @Override
                                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                                    TextView item = (TextView) super.getView(position,convertView,parent);
                                    String itemText = super.getItem(position);
                                    if (itemText.matches("<span id=\".+")){
                                        item.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF9933"));
                                        item.setTypeface(item.getTypeface(), Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
                                        item.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,20);
                                        item.setText(itemText.replaceAll("<span id=\\\\\"", ""));
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                            item.setTextColor(getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_light));
                                        }
                                        item.setTypeface(null,Typeface.NORMAL);
                                        item.setTextSize(14);
                                        item.setText(itemText.replaceAll("<span id=\\\\\"", ""));

                                    }
                                    return item;
                                }
```

Comment: this just made the list completely empty

Comment: But before you put the question was something on ListView?

Comment: The code I provided does populate the view. My problem is that I've changed getView to customise certain rows, but it doesn't seem to be called at any point

Comment: For me is working, I created a sample, please verify that you have Internet permission in your manifest

Comment: What do you mean with "I've changed getView to customise certain rows, but it doesn't seem to be called at any point" I've just copied your code, created a sample code and is working for me....

Comment: I definitely have internet permissions as I can populate the list. By change I meant overwritten. I want to find the <span tag with regex which indicates a heading, and then make it bold, larger font and coloured but this never happens, I just have plain text.

Comment: if you dont mind could I see a screenshot of what you have, and possibly a copy of your project?

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much, I completely overlooked that I had already replaced \\\\\" with \" which is why the regex was failing. Could you explain what the tricky else statement does, and why in the first place would scrolling screw up other textviews?

Comment: Because it will enter onbindviewholder and will repaint the others items from the list and the previous one are not reseted, so else simply reset the textviews

Comment: if it helpedfeel free to mark my answer as a correct one and upvote it :D